# How Do I Set case Fan Speed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

I want create code which set speed on chassis fan and must working on windows 7.

I try use WMI code creator but i got error  `Invalid object path`

```
    using System;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WMISample
    {
        public class CallWMIMethod
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementObject classInstance = 
                        new ManagementObject("root\\CIMV2", 
                        "Win32_Fan.ReplaceKeyPropery='ReplaceKeyPropertyValue'",
                        null);

                    // Obtain in-parameters for the method
                    ManagementBaseObject inParams = 
                        classInstance.GetMethodParameters("SetSpeed");

                    // Add the input parameters.
                    inParams["DesiredSpeed"] =  600;

                    // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
                    ManagementBaseObject outParams = 
                        classInstance.InvokeMethod("SetSpeed", inParams, null);

                    // List outParams
                    Console.WriteLine("Out parameters:");
                    Console.WriteLine("ReturnValue: " + outParams["ReturnValue"]);
                }
                catch(ManagementException err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is there any possibility refer to case fan. Any help can be appreciated ?

Comment: Didn't you ask this an hour ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277632/fan-set-speed-on-windows

Comment: According to MSDN, `SetSpeed` is not implemented for `Win32_Fan`, so I would suppose you get the error at `classInstance.GetMethodParameters("SetSpeed");` for that reason

Comment: What line generates the error?

Comment: program compiles, this error show up after run

Answer (score 2):

You code compiles because it is valid code.  It fails at runtime because you are asking it to do something illegal.  According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394146(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **SetSpeed**          Not implemented.

That being the case, this line will fail:

```
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = 
        classInstance.GetMethodParameters("SetSpeed");
```

If `SetSpeed` is *not implemented* (versus simply ignored) you will get an exception trying to retrieve params related to it. Remove the Try/Catch to verify which line it happens on.

The manufacturer may have a utility which allows this, but it seems doubtful WMI will work.  If you do find such a tool, you might want to evaluate the bool property `VariableSpeed` to see if variable speeds are even supported.

Comment: *The system manufacturer may have a utility which allows this* but you ought to check if the fan even supports variable speeds, first (check the `VariableSpeed` bool property)